# Backlight flashes quickly and then turns off on boot (and stays off)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, acer-aspire, backlight

On an Acer Aspire 47302 the backlight is **off** most of the time. When any of the following things happens, the backlight flashes on briefly, changes levels a few times, then turns off.

- The computer turns on
- I press Ctrl+Alt+Up to change the display orientation
- I plug the computer into an external VGA display

I've tried reinstalling the driver software, but that's about it. Does anybody know what might be going on?

EDIT: this used to say "is **on** most of the time." which made it both confusing and wrong.

Comment: Faulty inverter?

Comment: @joeqwerty how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Whether it's the backlight or the inverter, you can usually find replacements online. - https://www.google.com/#q=Acer+Aspire+47302+display+inverter